# Why function from .so library return random value?

Tags: python, c

I wrote small library on C for calculating function. This is fragment of this library:

```
// Расчёт функции
struct function_value function(double x) {
        struct function_value result;
        result.argument = x;
        for (int i=1; 1; i++) {
                double element = pow(-1.0,i+1) * (pow(VAR*x,i+(i-1)) / fact(i+(i-1)));
                if (fabs(element) < EPSILON) break; 
                else result.value += element;
        }
        return result;
}
```

And bind this library to small python program:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL("../gmath/lib/gmathlib.so")


class FunctionValue(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("argument", c_double), ("value", c_double)]


arg = c_double(-2.0)
libc.function.restype = FunctionValue
print(libc.function(arg).value)
i = -2.0
while i <= 2.0:
    i += 0.25
    result = libc.function(c_double(i)).value
    print(result)
```

But the program sometimes outputs the correct values of the function (image 1), sometimes displays one random number (image 2). Why is this happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Stargateur The code is plain text, only the output is images.

Comment: @Barmar There is no faq for "imageofoutput", still this deserve a downvote according by [help] of stackoverflow. Don't put image when you can use text.

Comment: PIcky, picky. The detailed output isn't even that important to the question.

Comment: @Barmar That don't matter (without see the image how to know if it's important) plus a lot of user don't activate image on SO and a lot of user use SO with limited data connection. That why SO is clear about don't post image unless there is no other solution. One other reason is for indexing of this question in search engine, images are not suitable to this. Here the obvious solution is to use basic feature of terminal emulation call "copy/paste" ;).

Comment: Seems like you're just looking for an excuse to downvote. What would be indexed if he'd posted that as text? It's just a bunch of random floating point numbers.

Comment: @Barmar Please, I don't invent all these rules, you have been on SO for 5 years, you should know this basic rule. I don't really want downvote this question cause it's a good question without the fact of image instead of text, still you want me that I don't downvote to be "nice" ? This don't make sense this user need to know that it's bad to post image instead of text for his/her future question ! It more you that don't want that people downvote question, my vote are my votes, it doesn't concern you.

Comment: I know the rules, I also try to apply common sense. And just because something isn't posted in the best way is no reason to downvote it. You don't have to upvote it, just leave it alone. But you can vote as you like, at least you left a comment, which is better than most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never initialized `result.value`, so `result.value += element;` is adding to an uninitialized variable.

```
struct function_value function(double x) {
    struct function_value result;
    result.argument = x;
    result.value = 0;
    for (int i=1; 1; i++) {
        double element = pow(-1.0,i+1) * (pow(VAR*x,i+(i-1)) / fact(i+(i-1)));
        if (fabs(element) < EPSILON) break; 
        else result.value += element;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Might be zero sometimes, just by chance.  Others, it some random value.

Comment: `struct function_value result = {.argument = x, .value = 0};`